# Where can I download Lockheed-Martin social network engine source code?

Tags: open-source, social-networking

I've read multiple times that Lockheed-Martin releases their social network implementation to open source. But I've never managed to actually find any piece of code - only news here and there. Do you know where the source is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get to the source code on the github project: [github.com](http://github.com/lmco/eurekastreams)

Answer (score 1):

I read the press release here:
http://www.lockheedmartin.com/news/press_releases/2009/070709_LMtoReleaseSocialMediaOpenSource.html

It doesn't say anything about it being free, though, only open source. I suspect you still have to buy the product, but are then given the source and are licensed to modify it etc.

Answer (score 1):

Engineering giant Lockheed Martin has used **Microsoft's SharePoint 3.0 with Active Directory 2003**, along with a Google search appliance, to build a home grown alternative to Facebook, but the technology is easier implement than the policies surrounding social networking. (That's old...)

Similar

- [White paper: Managing social
  networking with Microsoft Office
  SharePoint Server 2007](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262436%28office.12%29.aspx)
- [Social Sites™ Enterprise - Social 
  Computing for Business](http://www.newsgator.com/Business/SocialSites/Default.aspx) (Commerical)
- [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/products/collaboration/) (Open Source)